# Npm remove all packages that no more exist in package.json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, package

I'd like to remove all packages (in node_modules) that no more exist in **package.json** (these packages' name have been removed by another developer and the **package.json** file is modified on git).

How can i do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does that package names is written in `package.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following command:

```
npm prune
```

Description can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune)

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm prune` to unbuild modules not listed in package.json.

To know more  `npm help prune`:

This command removes "extraneous" packages. If a package name is provided, then only packages matching one of the supplied names are removed.

You can go with details [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune)